# Select a random string from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: Getting random value from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/javascript-getting-random-value-from-an-array)

Could someone help me on this topic? I've got this code.

```
var textArray = [
    'song1.ogg',
    'song2.ogg'
]
audioElement.setAttribute('src', textArray);
```

How can I randomly get one of those strings into my audio element?

Would be glad if someone can help....

Comment: http://blog.mastykarz.nl/jquery-random-filter/ Here is a way you can do it with a JQuery Extension.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

```
var textArray = [
    'song1.ogg',
    'song2.ogg'
];
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*textArray.length);

audioElement.setAttribute('src', textArray[randomNumber]);
```

Comment: had a little spelling mistake (length should be without capital), but fixed it in my answer

Comment: Yeah thanks you told me. It didn't work first but now it does. Thanks! By the way is it really needed to put a semicolon after every line?

Comment: yes, you need a semicolon to terminate every statement in javascript. also, please mark Gidon's answer as correct if it solves your problem.

Comment: @jbabey: That is incorrect. JavaScript inserts semicolons automatically, but because it is not perfect, it does not always insert them at the right place. So, you don't *have to* use semicolons, but you *really really should*.

Comment: Thanks to you all. I marked it as correct. I forgot that becuase of the timespan I have to wait to do that...

Answer (score 22):

```
var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * textArray.length); 
var randomElement = textArray[randomIndex];
```